# Android app stops when is calling data in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to display the data in a ListView, but my app stops running. I have a method in an other activity class, the method: `public List <Presentation> getAllPresentations() {..}` and i want to view this data in the ListView like below:

```
public class view_presentations extends Activity
{
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_presentation);

        List<Presentation> list = db.getAllPresentations();
        ListView l = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        l.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Presentation>(view_presentations.this, R.layout.view_presentation, list));

        db.closeDB();
    }
}
```

This is the output in LogCat:

```
06-03 17:46:22.123: W/dalvikvm(27677): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40adf228)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ricordiemotivi/com.example.ricordiemotivi.view_presentations}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at com.example.ricordiemotivi.view_presentations.onCreate(view_presentations.java:24)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
06-03 17:46:22.163: E/AndroidRuntime(27677):    ... 11 more
```

I tested the database output and everything is ok.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You have not initialize `db`. When you call `db.getAllPresentations()` you get `NullPointerException` cause `db` is null. In onCreate

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Comment: view_presentation is different from view_presentations .. and yes the database is initialized.

Comment: @user3659691 post the stacktrace if the app crashes and indicate line 24 in your activity. I don't see where it is initialized

Comment: @user3659691 you still use the same layout  `R.layout.view_presentation` you set the same to the activity and the same as a param to adapter constructor. I was right see again. `view_presentations.this` represents activity context. I am talking about the second param

Comment: @user3659691 also follow java naming conventions to avoid confusion. Class name begins with caps

Answer (score 0):

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(...);
```

Comment: the db is initialized.. i've said that i have a a output, but in the listview the app terminate.

Comment: @user3659691 please post the code where your DatabaseHelper object is being initialized.